# PFUser currentUser returns nil after Facebook Login with Parse SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I'm currently developing an iOS App that allows login via Facebook/Parse. The login flow goes like this:

- login button is touched and Facebook login window opens;
- user logs in and gives permission on Facebook;
- app retrieves Facebook accessToken information;
- app performs [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackGroundWithAccessToken:(accessToken) ^block{}] to make the Parse login authentication;
- app goes to a view and tries to perform a query to fetch data associated with that user from Parse.

The problem is: after logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken is performed, [PFUser currentUser] returns nil, and I get a "Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! Solved it!

After digging into the code a little further I realized that the

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken:(accessToken) block:^(nullable__block){}];
```

callback wasn't being executed for unknown reasons.

To solve this I added a check into the view's -viewDidLoad method to see if there was a valid [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] but NOT a valid [PFUser currentUser], and if so I forced the method to be executed.

If you need a more thorough explanation, don't hesitate to leave your comment! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((currentUser != nil)) {

        if (PFFacebookUtils.isLinkedWithUser(currentUser!)) {
            proccessCurrent(currentUser!)

        } else {
            PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(currentUser!, withReadPermissions: self.facebookReadPermissions, block: {(success, error) in
                if (success) {
                    self.proccessCurrent(currentUser!)

                } else {
                    self.presentWalkThroughViewController()
                }
            })


        }
    } else {
        //var currentToken: FBSDKAccessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()

        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil) {
            self.presentWalkThroughViewController()

        } else {
            var currentToken: FBSDKAccessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
                PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken(currentToken, block: {(user, error) in
                if (error == nil) {
                    user?.pinInBackgroundWithBlock({(success, error) in
                        if (success) {
                            self.proccessCurrent(user!)
                        } else {
                           self.presentWalkThroughViewController()
                        }

                    })
                } else {
                    self.presentWalkThroughViewController()
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

The methods processCurrentUser, continue to process my program execution and presentWalkThroughViewController presents the login screens.  Is this a safe way to handle skipping the login screen on facebook once a user is already logged in?